# CGridview Filters do not seem to be working

Tags: filter, yii, cgridview

Can some one please help me with my filters, they do not seem to be getting data from the database.

View that has the CGridview

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'user-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'enablePagination'=>true,
'pager'=>array(
    'maxButtonCount'=>'7',
),
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name'=>'bt_number',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>$model->bt_number,

    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'date_time',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>$model->date_time,
    ),
            array(
        'name'=>'broker',
        'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>$model->broker,
        'filter'=>Yii::app()->params['brokers'],

    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}{update}'
    ),
)
));
```

Model the model, I have tried to print out one of the search elements I wa filtering on not nothing display

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    echo "booker ".$this->broker;// exit;
           //above only displays booker there is nothing in $this->broker

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('bt_number',$this->bt_number);
    $criteria->compare('sign',$this->sign,true);
    $criteria->compare('fm_buys',$this->fm_buys,true);
    $criteria->compare('fm_buys_amt',$this->fm_buys_amt,true);
    $criteria->compare('against',$this->against,true);
    $criteria->compare('bt_sett_date',$this->bt_sett_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('bt_order_type',$this->bt_order_type,true);
    $criteria->compare('date_time',$this->date_time,true);
    $criteria->compare('dealer',$this->dealer,true);
    $criteria->compare('rate',$this->rate,true);
    $criteria->compare('broker',$this->broker,true);
    $criteria->compare('recapped',$this->recapped,true);
    $criteria->compare('settled',$this->settled,true);
    $criteria->compare('sett_date',$this->sett_date,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Controller is not getting anything from the $_GET var

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model=new BrokerTrades('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['BrokerTrades']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['BrokerTrades'];

    print_r($_GET)  ;
    $this->render('index',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

I can not see why this filter is not work please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure each of the fields you want to filter is set to safe in the rules of the model.

```
public function rules(){
  return array(
    ..
    array('bt_number,sign,fmbuys','safe','on'=>'search'),
  );
}
```

The attributes need to be set the safe in order for this line to function:

`$model->attributes=$_GET['BrokerTrades'];`

Just include all the attributes you want to search by in the first string, separated by commas.

See if that helps at all.